# Wordpress woocommerce shortcode execution

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a content which is created and loaded by a third party plugin. In this content, I have placed a WooCommerce shortcode. This shortcode is not interpreted and is displayed as-is (a string of characters), which is all rational as the content is not passed through WooCommerce's shortcode associated functions.

Now, how should I add a function to interpret the content for the WooCommerce shortcodes. I mean, in other words, which function of WooCommerce/Wordpress should I use to translate that shortcode.

Comment: In php you will need to use `echo do_shortcode('[my_shortcode]');` function, see [**this reference**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/). you have a lot of different examples near the end. Welcome to Wordpress/WooCommerce word :)